# Delete all subcollections of a particular document(eg.currentuser doc) in a collection when app is killed in kotlin/android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection which has a subcollection.I do not want to delete the collection,but I want to delete all subcollections of a particular document(i.e.currentuser doc) when user kills the app.

I tried doing this using batch operations from client side.But then that only deletes the collection documents data,it does not delete the subcollection:

In my case it deletes gamingemail(which is the collections(AllUsers)->document->field value),but I want to know how to delete the subcollection(Request) of the particular document.

Firestore Screenshot:
[image]

Kotlin Code used to delete collection data:

```js
class onAppKilled: Service() {
    private lateinit var mFirestore:FirebaseFirestore
    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    lateinit var currentUser: FirebaseUser
    private val EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 4,
            60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, LinkedBlockingQueue())
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }


    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {

        mFirestore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        currentUser= mAuth!!.currentUser!!

        currentUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener {task->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this@onAppKilled,"User Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this@onAppKilled,"User not deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }
        })
        val colref= mFirestore.collection("AllUsers")
        deleteCollection(colref,EXECUTOR)
    }
     fun deleteCollection(collection: CollectionReference, executor: Executor) {
        Tasks.call(executor, Callable<Void>{
            val batchSize:Int = 100
            var query = collection.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId()).limit(batchSize.toLong())
            var deleted = deleteQueryBatch(query)

            while (deleted.size>= batchSize) {
                val last = deleted[deleted.size - 1]
                query = collection.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId()).startAfter(last.getId()).limit(batchSize.toLong())

                deleted = deleteQueryBatch(query)
            }
            null
        })
    }
    @WorkerThread
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun deleteQueryBatch(query: Query): List<DocumentSnapshot> {
        val querySnapshot = Tasks.await(query.get())

        val batch = query.getFirestore().batch()
        for (snapshot in querySnapshot) {
            val a =SplitString(currentUser.email!!)
            if(snapshot.get("gamingfirstemail")==SplitString(currentUser.email!!)){
                batch.delete(snapshot.getReference())
            }
        }
        Tasks.await(batch.commit())
        return querySnapshot.getDocuments()
    }

    fun SplitString(str:String):String{
        val name=str.split("@")
        return name[0]
    }


}
```

When trying to delete doc in subcollection using the same way above and replacing I get the below errors in my logcat:

```js
 val colref= mFirestore.collection("AllUsers").document("sira").collection("Request")
```

> 03-17 16:48:29.098 2759-3249/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=1550, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
>   03-17 16:48:29.157 3320-3566/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f36f6f440
>   03-17 16:48:36.023 21400-21456/? E/MAL-Daemon:  (void* rilproxy_task_hdl(,  439) rilproxy_task_hdl(), receive event = 401
>   03-17 16:48:39.771 16200-17680/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xcf1469c0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xe5274b44 arg=0x0
>   03-17 16:48:39.772 16200-17680/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xcf1469c0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
>   03-17 16:48:40.224 16200-17682/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xd0e6a640 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xe4afeb44 arg=0x0
>       ssl=0xd0e6a640 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
>   03-17 16:48:40.243 16200-17683/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xd0e6b040 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xd4952b44 arg=0x0
>   03-17 16:48:40.244 16200-17683/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xd0e6b040 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
>   03-17 16:48:40.340 12522-17744/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f732cee80 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f592fe5b0 arg=0x0
>       ssl=0x7f732cee80 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
>   03-17 16:48:46.024 21400-21456/? E/MAL-Daemon:  (void* rilproxy_task_hdl(,  439) rilproxy_task_hdl(), receive event = 401
>   03-17 16:48:48.778 17207-17760/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xd025f000 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xd4eb4764 arg=0x0
>   03-17 16:48:48.779 17207-17760/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xd025f000 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
>   03-17 16:48:48.800 17207-17762/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xd0260180 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xd4b84764 arg=0x0
>       ssl=0xd0260180 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA

How to delete subcollections data for particular document from client side?

Comment: @AlexMamo: since you requested opening a new question, can you have a look?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure puf, just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in your code, you are trying to delete all documents that exist within `colref` collection. Using that code, you're able to delete all documents but not the subcollections that exist within each document. Most likely, those documents are now displayed in ***italic*** since there are no more properties. But please note, this is the expected behavior.

In Cloud Firestore documents and subcollections don't work like filesystem files and directories. Subcollections are not tied in any way to a parent document. So when you delete a collection by finding all documents within it, it doesn't mean that you are also deleting all subcollections that exist within those documents.

So to be able to delete an entire collection, fist you have to find all subcollections that exist at the lowest level, in your case `Request`. If there aren't any other subcollections in those documents (I cannot see from the screenshot you have provided), first you have to find all documents that exist there and delete them. Only then, as a second operation you should delete the documents that exist beneath your `AllUsers` collection.

As a conclusion, delete all subcollections from the lowest level to the highest level.

According to the official documentation, for large collections, the delete operation is not recommended because it has negative security and performance implications. You can still do it for small collections of documents. For large collections I still recommend you to use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections).

Comment: You mentioned to find all documents of subcollection existing in lowest level.So for a moment  forget about the collection,I tried doing the same thing above for subcollection where val colref= mFirestore.collection("AllUsers").document(SplitString(currentUser.email)).collection("Request") but nothing happened and it was not deleted.So is that the right thing to do,is that possible directly accessing subcollection instead of collection?

Comment: Have you tried to hardcode  `SplitString(currentUser.email)` let's say with `aaba`? Does it work this way?

Comment: Yes i tried a doc name(eg:aaba) in place of SplitString(currentUser.email),it did not work for me,nothing happened.

Comment: Right now my firestore rule is :   allow read, write;.Do I need to specify/add some rules in firestore in order to access subcollections as subcollection is not being accessed even by hardcoding?

Comment: So you basically say that it's working with a collection but it's not with a subcollection, right? Have you tried to set write rules true for testing purposes? Have you also tried to delete a single document, does it work?

Comment: For testing purpose read and write is allowed.Yes,its working with a collection(both hardcoded and dynamically)(i.e.the document in the collection and the collection name are deleted) but with subcollection  its not working.Also when trying to delete single subcollection document(both hardcoded and dynamically),nothing happens,and subcollection is not deleted,shows me a bunch of errors which I cant understand.I will post the errors i get above.

Comment: I have also tried to delete subcollection if only particular document key exists as such if(snapshot.get("key")==value){
                batch.delete(snapshot.getReference())
            },but this does not work in case of subcollections but works for collections.

Comment: So you say that `mFirestore.collection("AllUsers").document("aaba").collection("Request").document("9c2s ... PCrE").delete()` doesn't work either, right?

Comment: Right.I tried that.That also does not work,so basically I am not able to access the subcollection in any way.I read that it is not possible to access  subcollection values,but is it not possible to delete subcollections also?

Comment: If a simple delete operation doesn't work, I think it's about security rules. Have you tried to add a complete listener to the delete operation and log the error message, what does it say? It is possible to access and delete documents within any collection or subcollection as long as the security rules allow that.

Comment: I tried adding a addOnCompleteListener but it does not log anything,tried debugging but that whole func itself does not run,when using addOnSuccessListener also it does not log out anything,on debugging it reaches the addonfailurelistener part and just crashes,it wont enter the failure part.It could be a security issue,but i dont get any PERMISSION_DENIED firestore error.Is there something i need to add to my firestore rules to access subcoll.Right now my rule just reads allow read and write?

Comment: For testing purposes, just use the default rules set to true. When it crashes, it crashes with what error?

Comment: I can delete subcollections now using         mFirestore.collection("AllUsers").document("aasta").collection("Request").document("pqrstuvw").delete()...I tried the same thing before and even now but it was crashing.The only thing I did was delete and repaste the same rule in my firestore,i dint change the rule its the same,but after updating it now I can delete subcollections...Why like that?

Comment: I am very confused right now.Without doing anything and just refreshing the firestore rules how can I delete subcollections now?

Comment: If the delete operation works now just use the logic I have explained in my answer, right?

Comment: But I still cannot delete the subcollections using batch operations...only using hardcoded delete() I can delete it.I am using the same logic above to delete subcollections.

Comment: Then is seems that is something wrong in your code. Try to debug it, find the issue and it will work for sure. Keep me posted.

Comment: I can now delete subcollections via batch operations and it works fine.I did nested querying inside the collections when finding the collection document but Im not sure if this is the right way.Should I post it as an answer or edit the question?

Comment: Good to hear that it finally worked :) Yes, that normal, as I already said to you, to delete all subcollections you cannot do in a single go so nested queries are normal.

Comment: Yes you mentioned about not doing it in single go,and I was trying the nested way only.But earlier I was not able to reach till my subcollections but after updating same firestore rules I am able to,weird.But now all works fine.Thanks again,appreciate the help.